# QIODevice::read error while opening XML

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having problems using a basic dialog to open an XML file for parsing.
My compile output is always giving me the error **QIODevice::read: device not open** even if the path and the file actually exists and i'm selecting it through the dialog window.

```
void eltechdb::carica() 
{

    QXmlStreamReader filecarica;
    QString nomefile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Carica database"), ".",tr("File XML (*.xml)"));

    QFile file(nomefile);
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    filecarica.setDevice(&file);
    filecarica.readNext();

    while(!filecarica.atEnd())
    {
        ....
    }

    file.close();

}
```

What could be the problem? I'm getting no errors from the compilers but it seems like it cannot read the file.

I already tried it to place it on the root folder without any results. In addition, you should know that the files are generated (correctly) through the QXmlStreamWrite library using the same kind of dialog successfully.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you can't open a file -- not sure what XML has to do with any of this?

Comment: Check return value of `file.open()` and value of `file.errorString()`.